# Using SwiftUI Charts in macOS Foundation App

Tags: swift, swiftui, nsviewcontroller, swiftui-charts

I have a Foundation macOS App written in Swift. I'm trying to use SwiftUI Chart View in NSViewcontroller (tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOdZuBIBQWA)) but it's seems `import Charts` doesn't recognized and I obtain the error `Cannot find 'Chart' in scope` and `Cannot find 'LineMark' in scope`.

[image]

Any idea about the issue and how to resolve it ?

**EDIT n.1**

I've changed deployment target to macOS 13.0+ but still have the same error.

**EDIT n.2**

I've tried with this sintax (using foreach inside construction closure) but still have the same error.

```
var body: some View {
        Chart {
            ForEach(entries) { entry in
                LineMark(x: .value("Time", entry.time),
                         y: .value("Temp", entry.temp))
                .foregroundStyle(.red)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: is your app support Mac 13.0 and above? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts/chart

Comment: nope, actually 12.0 +

Comment: Well there you go. Question answered.

Comment: I've changed in 13.0+ but I still have the same error.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? Also, have you included any other packages named `Charts`?

Comment: Xcode 14.2 for the import, I only imported this three packages import SwiftUI, import Charts, import Foundation

Comment: Upgraded to Xcode 14.3, same issue. I'm struggling... I can't resolve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Charts 3rd party library by any chance in your project?

This one? https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

if so work around needs to be renaming Charts library to DGCharts, they are already working on it but this issue explains it

https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/4897

my solution would be:
or if you are using cocoa pods you can use
`pod 'DGCharts', :git => 'https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts.git' , :branch => 'release/5.0.0'`

Answer (score -1):

I believe there may be a bug in Xcode.

I encountered the same issue as you did on my development environment (Ventura 13.0, Xcode 14.2, and Minimum Deployments macOS 13.0) on my first attempt. **However, as I made various tweaks to the code to try to resolve the issue, the error suddenly vanished, and I was able to build without any problem.** It was so weird.

There is a syntax that allows you to use `Charts` in a manner similar to the ForEach syntax, as follows:

```swift
Chart(entries, id: \.temp) { entry in
    ...
    ...
}
```

I suspect that Xcode's inference capabilities are causing some unknown conflict with that constructor (or others).

Therefore, instead of using the syntax in your example, I would recommend using the syntax with `id:` mentioned above, or the syntax utilizing `ForEach` from the [Apple tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts/chart) (hopefully with a bug fix).

```swift
struct WeatherTemperature : Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let temp: Double
    let time: Int
}

struct ContentView : View {
    let entries = [
        WeatherTemperature(temp: 10, time: 1680622832),
        WeatherTemperature(temp: 14, time: 1680622932)
    ]
    
    var body : some View {
        Chart {
            ForEach(entries) { entry in
                LineMark(x: .value("Time", entry.time),
                         y: .value("Temp", entry.temp))
                .foregroundStyle(.red)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried following your suggestions, but without success. I always got the same error, that's really weird.